# How to add Python Egg to Eclipse Pydev paths? New Egg button not behaving as expected

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to add a python egg to my eclipse pydev path via Eclipse Settings -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python -> New Egg/Zip(s), and in the dialog where I browse to the egg file, and click the "open" button on the dialog, it simply keeps the dialog open and browses into the egg.

This is on OS X with Helios SR 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this only on OS X, but simple solution was to just add the egg as a folder via New Folder.  I'm guessing the New Egg/Zip button is for OS's that don't treat Zips/Eggs as folders.

Comment: Probably you had the egg unzipped then (the zips/eggs is for when the egg is zipped, otherwise, when unzipped, as you saw, just add it as a folder).

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac I have some .egg's that are files, and some .egg's that are folders, for example my SQLObject is a folder but my oauth is a file.  I am not exactly sure why, it could be because of how I downloaded and installed them.

The ones that are folders can't be chosen by the "Add zip/jar/egg" chooser, but the simple solution is just to include those via "Add source folder".

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python, Iron python, or Jython) > Libraries

You can add a new folder, using the New folder Button,
You can add a new egg, using the New Egg button,
or remove.

If you are experimenting with new versions of libraries, I suggest to remove the old versions, restart eclipse, install the new ones, then restart eclipse again.

Cheers !! happy PyDeving !!